# Which Mobile Devices Support Databases like SQLite?

Tags: iphone, android, sqlite, symbian

Which Mobile Devices Support Databases ?

Iphone, Android, Symbian, J2ME, Palm, BlackBerry ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **iPhone supports SQLite**, since it's written in C, (Objective C being a superset of C). You can also use the native framework for persistent data, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) which is usually used with a SQLite Data Store
- **Android supports SQLite**, it has [a package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) which is the standard package for database on the plateform
- **Symbian supports SQLite**, in fact it's built in the OS (as per [SQLite page](http://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html))
- **J2ME does not support SQLite**, though there is [other options](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME)
- **Blackberry supports SQLite** since version 5 of its OS : [Date Storage Overview](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Data_storage_overview_1219751_11.jsp)

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is specially design for light weight device like Mobile. So all the Mobile devices support the SQLite database